# Overlaying of raster in GRASS for visualization?

Tags: grass-gis

I have generated  insolation time rasters map in grass using r.sun module.

How to overlay insolation time rasters over DSM depicting the color table for visualization?

Answer (score 2):

In GRASS GIS GUI add your DSM to *Layer Manager* (and remove or disable all the other layers). Set computational region to match the DSM (e.g. in map layer context menu) and zoom to it. Then switch to *3D view* in *Map Display*.

In *3D view* tab go to *Data* tab. Set *Fine mode resolution* to 1 or 2. In *Surface attributes* box below, set *Color* to *map* and select there your insolation time raster from `r.sun` (*map* should be set by default and the name of the raster map will be your DSM by default).

Find a detailed guide here:

http://www4.ncsu.edu/~akratoc/GRASS_intro/

And a video tutorial here:

http://courses.ncsu.edu/mea582/common/media/03/sc_wxnviz1_edit1large.mov